# EF Core affected 0 rows on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I having following code:

```
using var db = new DataContext();
var foobar = db.Foobar.First();
foobar.NavProperties.Add(new NavProperty());
db.SaveChanges();
```

And get this error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

What could cause this error? Any ideas? Please tell me if I need to provide more information.
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Checking the query via profiler tool can help

Comment: Which profiler tool do you mean? :)

Comment: sql server has profiler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Other databases might have something similiar to sql profiler to trace queries.

Comment: Does the class `NavProperty` have any properties?  Does it have an autogenerated primary key?  Possibly the fact that you didn't set any properties resulted in a no-op (since there may have been no data to insert) and thus nothing actually got committed to the database.

Comment: Is the `NavProperties` property actually mapped to the database? If `NavProperty` object is mapped, can you do `db.NavProperties.Add(new NavProperty() { foobarid = foobar.id });` ?

Comment: @KirkWoll The `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute was missing on `Id` property. Feel free to post it as an answer and I accept it of course.

Comment: @Wolle, I'm glad you figured it out.  I encourage you to post this as an answer. (self-answered questions are encouraged!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kirk Woll's hint, I figured out that my entities primary key declaration was missing the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute and only looked like this:

```
[Key] 
public int Id { get; set; }
```

So I just had to change it to:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
public int Id { get; set; }
```